# Regression with indicator

Tags: r, regression, indicator

I have a dataset with one dependent variable y, and two independent x(continuous) and z(indicator with 0 or 1). The model I would I like to fit is

```
y = a*1(z==0) + b*x*1(z==1),
```

in other words, if z==0 then the estimate should simply be the intercept, otherwise the estimate should be the intercept plus the b*x part.

The only thing I have come up with is to do it in 2 steps, ie first take the mean of y for which z==0 (this is the estimate of the intercept), and then subtract this value from the rest of the ys and run a simple regression to estimate the slope.

I am (almost) sure this will work, but ideally I would like to get the estimates in a one-liner in R using lm or something similar. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new variable which is 0 if `z` is 0, and equal to `x` otherwise:

```
y ~ ifelse(z, x, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by just fitting the interaction:

```
fit <- lm( y ~ x:z )
```

This will multiply x by z so that when z is 0 the value of x will have no influence and when z is one it will just fit x.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be tackled in two ways:

a) First create two dummies when `z`=0 and when `z`=1 (lets say this is `z0` and `z1` : `with(mydata,ifelse (z==1,z0,z1))` and include both in the model and run the following model without intercept:

`lm(y~as.factor(z)+x-1,data=mydata)` or `lm(y~z0+z1+x-1,data=mydata`) #model includes two dummies without intercept to avoid dummy variable trap

`y=b0z0+b1z1+b2x`

b)Second include only one dummy (`z=1`) and run the following model with intercept

`lm(y~z1+x,data=mydata`) #model includes one dummy with intercept

`y=intercept+b1z1+b2x` #coefficient on z1 gives incremental value over z=0

Expected value of y when z1=0 is intercept+ b2x and expected value of y when z1=1 is intercept+ b1z1+b2x. The difference is b1z1.

Note: This is more related to statistics rather than to programming. So, you will be better of asking these type of questions in [CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).